# Entity Translation broken

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

When I create a node with entity translation and choose a language the field body is wrong.

```
language = 'en'
field_body[und].
```

This only happens with a specific content type and with new ones, not with others.
What's broken?
What can I check?

Comment: Check that your body field can be translatable.

Comment: Yes it is. In the other content types it works. Translation is a common setting.

Comment: Ciao Carlo, abbiamo lo stesso problema, l'abbiamo risolto in modo molto fantasioso: attiviamo uno dei menù disponibili nel tab impostazioni del menù del CT. Non riusciamo a capire perché, se hai nuove notizie ti prego di segnalarle, grazie Giovanna Hello Carlo, we have the same problem, we have solved it in a very imaginative way: we activate one of the menus available in the settings tab of the CT menu. We can not understand why, if you have new news, please let me know, thanks Giovanna